# Recursive XSD definition

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to write a recursive XSD definition. I looked at similar questions but I'm still unable to find what I'm doing wrong.

I'm defining a header which is an item that has a text, an URL and a list of children items.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="header">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="item">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="url"/>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="item" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>
```

My IDE gives an error in the nested item saying that "item" is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the `item` element locally, but it has to be defined globally in order to be referenced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="text"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="url"/>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="item" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="header">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="item"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```